# How to clean a keyboard in Toshiba laptop?

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

I have Toshiba Satellite Pro P300-1CG with slim keyboard. I haven't spilled anything major on it, but I often eat in front of the laptop while watching some videos. Therefore small drops of milk and other liquids often leave spots at the laptop and sometimes go between keys. And it's not to mention small dust particles that have been falling though during last 1.5 years.

It's not that my keyboard is working badly, but I would like to have it clean. I assume I need to disassemble it. How do I do it? I would like to avoid disassembling whole laptop and there is suspicious plastic holder on the top of the keyboard (see picture) - maybe I can use it to remove just keyboard? Also keys don't go off if I just pull them up with the knife. Should I do it at all (maybe the risk to break something is too high)?

[image: Laptop]

Comment: I can't find the service manual for your laptop now, but mine looks relatively similar. You've got little "thingies" on top of your keyboard, right of esc key, right of f4, right of f8 ... try pulling them down. If you manage to do that, then we're on a good way.

Comment: Found the "thingies", but they won't go down or up. Seems like they are bound to the keyboard. I am still suspicious about the long "thingie" above the first key row (Esc, F1, F2 etc.).

Comment: Btw, when I said go down I didn' mean down/up in terms of perpendicular to the keyboard plane. But down, towards the touchpad for example. ... In any case, it was worth a shot. Sorry it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

[image]

After removing this one can remove keyboard and clean it separately.

Answer (score 4):

Some [compressed air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_air) and some [rubbing alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbing_alcohol) will be fine.

1. Power down the computer, and remove
   the batter.
2. Next, wet some paper towels with the rubbing alcohol and wipe the keyboard down. It may be helpful to have some toothpicks and cotton swaps if you don't feel like popping the keys off the keyboard. Don't use too much rubbing alcohol or it won't dry out quickly.
3. Next use the compressed air to blow any remaining gunk out of the keyboard.
4. Allow it to dry for 5-10 minutes.
5. Power back up.

Just remember, [keyboards are on average dirtier then a toilet seat](http://www.geek.com/articles/gadgets/research-finds-out-just-how-dirty-your-keyboard-is-2008055/).

Comment: Where can I buy compressed air in Germany? I've heard so many times about this compressed air, but was never able to find one.

Comment: Just about any computer store should have it, it's a pretty common item. I'm not sure what the equivalent stores are, but Staples, Best Buy, Radio Shack, and most office supply stores will carry it.