# Cleaning the sticky keys of a touchpad on a laptop

Tags: laptop, touchpad, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unpacking a laptop touchpad to clean it](https://superuser.com/questions/116632/unpacking-a-laptop-touchpad-to-clean-it)

How do I access and clean the area around my laptop's touchpad?

I accidentally got some apple juice under my laptop keys. It was a very minimal amount but apple juice is quite sticky and therefore my buttons are very sticky and do not have that nice click any more. Is there anyway to safely clean under those buttons?

The touchpad buttons are quite flush with part you touch so there is only a small slit surrounding them.

[image: problem area needing clean on a laptop]

So far I've only come across articles on how to clean a laptop's keyboard but they only cover how to clean the exterior (stuff you see) but not the actual stuff under the touchpad buttons.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/115923/how-to-clean-a-keyboard-in-toshiba-laptop

Comment: @random you are wrong. It's quite different. My question relates to the actual buttons on the touch pad not the keys. The solution to fix it will not be the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is indeed a duplicate. The answers on the other blog lists solutions on how to clean under the key. Someone recommended using rubbing alcohol and a q-tip.

Comment: @Jay it's not a KEY it's a BUTTON. It's very flush to the touchpad and a Q-TIP would not fit in the small slit. I don't even think it can be removed, because of how flush it is.

Comment: Can you upload a photo of this key button? You're making it unclearer what part of the keyboard you want to clean now

Comment: @random there I edited with a arrow pointing to the problem area.